# what exactly is a variable under the hood in javascript?

Tags: javascript, frontend, computer-science

I understand that a variable that is assigned with an object is actually a pointer(reference) to object.
eg x=[1,2,3,4}, here x is a pointer to the memory location where the array is stored.

**But when i assign a primitive value to a variable , x=16 or x="abc", what is 'x' under the hood?**
Is it also a pointer(reference) to the memory where 16 is stored ? in case x is a reference here, and if i say y=x then why is the  value of x is copied to y? ( **if its a reference then ,y=x is suppose to make y point to the same memory location where x is pointing to right?**)

Comment: Read this: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-lexical-environments

Comment: you may find it instructive to view the the source for V8 primitives https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.12/d4/da0/v8_8h_source.html#l01582